# How to erase map of vector while travesing

Tags: vector, dictionary, erase

I have declared,

```
map<int, vector<int>> abcmap;
map<int,vector<int>>:: iterator itmap;

vector<int>SPLINKS;
```

SPLINKS contains:

```
1 3 4
```

abcmap contains;

```
1=> 1

2=> 2 6

3=> 1 2 4
```

I want to iterate both SPLINKS and abcmap to find and erase elements that do not match in both containers;

ie after execution;

```
2=>2 6     //not matched with either 1 or 3 or 4
```

I write something like;

```
for(itmap = abcmap.begin(); itmap != abcmap.end(); ++itmap)
{
cout << endl << itmap->first <<" => ";
for(size_t n=0; n<(*itmap).second.size(); n++)
{
for(itspl=SPLINKS.begin(); itspl!=SPLINKS.end(); ++itspl)
{
if((*itspl)==itmap->second[n])
{
    abcmap.erase(itmap);
}
}
}
}
```

But I get debug assertion failed!.

Can anyone please help me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: You should debug your code and try to solve problem yourself before posting here.

Comment: I know it erases the same iterator while traversing, as such it invalidates.
Can you help me how to solve this?

Comment: show the stack trace and we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

By "find and erase elements that do not match in both containers" I understand that you want to delete from map. Either way, it's easy to modify code to remove element from SPLINKS

Here is the code:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> map;
std::vector<int> vector = {1, 3, 4};
map[0] = {1};
map[1] = {2, 6, 5};
map[2] = {1, 2, 4};

for(auto &pair: map) { // iterate map
    auto &currentvec = pair.second;
    std::vector<int> values;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < currentvec.size(); i++) { // iterate vectors of map
        bool contains = false;
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < vector.size(); j++) { // iterate vector this be your SPLINKS
            if(currentvec[i] == vector[j]) {
            contains = true;
           }
        }
        if (!contains) {
            values.push_back(currentvec[i]);
        }
   }
   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
       currentvec.erase(std::remove(currentvec.begin(), currentvec.end(), values[i]), currentvec.end());
   }
}

for (auto &pair : map) { // iterate map
    auto &currentvec = pair.second;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < currentvec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << currentvec[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Headers required: `<map>`, `<vector>`, `<algorithm>`, `<iostream>`